# Splat in argument position

Tags: ruby, splat

Why does this code

```
Hash[*[[:first_name, 'Shane'], [:last_name, 'Harvie']].flatten]
```

return this

```
{:first_name=>"Shane", :last_name=>"Harvie"}
```

I know about `Array#flatten`. But what does the `*` mean? How can I look for information about it?

Answer (score 5):

It's so called splat operator. In this case it takes an array and "expands" it, producing a list of arguments to [`Hash.[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) call. Basically

```
Hash[*[[:first_name, 'Shane'], [:last_name, 'Harvie']].flatten]
```

is equivalent to this

```
Hash[*[:first_name, 'Shane', :last_name, 'Harvie']]
```

which is equivalent to this

```
Hash[:first_name, 'Shane', :last_name, 'Harvie']
```

Comment: I think it would be even better if you show the step after the application of `flatten` before the application of the splat operator.

Answer (score 2):

A simple splat operator example, in addition to Sergio's answer:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2)
  puts arg1
  puts arg2
end
args = ["bar", "baz"]

foo(args)
#=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

foo(*args)
#=> "bar"
#=> "baz"
```